# Why with some browsers i get a wrong value for my Session object?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am coding an asian language learning module for my mojoportal-based iphone-optimized website (work in progress, english resources are not fully translated: http://ilearn.dandandin.it/kanatrainer.aspx)

It's a simple "guess how to read this" game, with the right answer stored in a Session object.

I don't understand why, but, expecially using Safari, users will get someone else's Session value

This is an excerpt from the code (i removed some stuff, translated the variables)

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
        ...
        generateRandom();
        }
    }

    protected void generateRandom()
    {
        int i, j = 0, livello = 5, chance = 0;
        System.Random acaso = new Random();
        ...
        while (j <= 0)
        {
            j = acaso.Next((Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxlunghezza.Text) + 1));
        }
        ...
        for (int k = 0; k < j; k++)
        {
            i = acaso.Next(livello);
            Session["randomLetters"] += (globals.asianCharacters[i]);
            ...
        }
        ...
    }


    protected void AnswerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string compare = Server.HtmlEncode(InputTextBox.Text.ToLower());
        if (compare == "")
        {
            Label1.Text = ("You did not write anything");
            return;
        }
        if (Session["randomLetters"].ToString() != compare)
        {
            Label1.Text = ("Wrong!" + Session["randomLetters"]);
        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = ("Right!" + Session["randomLetters"]);
        }
     ...
    }
```

What happens in visual studio, with every browser:

randomLetters is "hello". User writes "hello" in the textbox, and "hello" is compared to "hello". Label says "Right! hello".

What happens in iis, only in webkit-based browsers:

randomLetters is "hello". User writes "hello" in the textbox, but "hello" is compared to "goodbye". Label says "Wrong! goodbye".

**I don't understand how Session["randomLetters"] has changed**

Public vs private code:
[image: the code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using HiddenFields i "solved" the problem (but i don't like that way)

Answer (score 0):

How are your storing the session state? Cookie? Database? so on... I have had many problems (usually with IE 8) with the way that the browser was caching the pages and the cookies. Usually, changing the respective setting in the browser fixed the problem. I don't know if that helps here. To make it more robust, I then have to find a way to notify the user when one of these settings is not right.

Comment: hmmm, I mean, how is the Session["name"] being stored on the server?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx

Comment: I think that it's stored on the server and retrieved by an identifier saved on a cookie, or passed values in url if cookie support it's disabled

Comment: It's not like that? Session["stuff"] = "other stuff";

Comment: I usually do 

if(Session["stuff"] == null)
    Session.Add("stuff", value);
else
    Session["stuff"] = value;

Comment: just do this Session[txtName.Text] = txtValue.Text; see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300437.aspx#S5

Comment: so the visual studio testing, were you just using the visual studio dev server and then the problem started when you switched to IIS?

Comment: debug target = no problem; release target, problem only on IIS, only with Safari and Chrome

Comment: Well, I was just going to say, that the Visual Studio Dev machine is the worst ever for being anything close to how the page will actually render in IIS.